# Interpretation of the obstruction class in terms of cells (Milnor-Stasheff 12.1)

Tags: differential-topology, characteristic-classes

In section 12 of Milnor-Stasheff's characteristic classes, they mentioned an obstruction class for the associated Stiefel manifold bundle $V_k(\xi)$ over $B$ as follows:

**Definition:** The *associated Stiefel manifold bundle* $V_k(\xi)$ over $B$ for an $n$-plane bundle $\xi$ over $B$ is defined as the bundle obtained from gluing $V_k(F_x)$, where $x\in B$, the base manifold and $F_x$ is a fibre of $\xi$ over $x$.

Existence of cross section of $V_k(\xi)$ over the $(n-k)$-skeleton of $B$ is guaranteed, but not for the cross section over the $(n-k+1)$-skeleton. There exists a cross section over the $(n-k+1)$-skeleton of $B$ iff some obstruction class in $H^{n-k+1}(B;\{\pi_{n-k}V_k(F)\})$ vanishes.

**Definition:** We use the notation $\mathfrak{o}_{n-k+1}(\xi)\in H^{n-k+1}(B;\{\pi_{n-k}V_k(F)\})$ to denote such obstruction class.

Now I am confused with the argument here in the proof of theorem 12.1:

[image]

In their construction there I can see why it gives a cross section over the $(n-1)$-skeleton, but why the obstruction cocycle "assign" the $n$-cell to a generator of the homotopy group in the very last line?

The argument to me there is not clear for me.

It will be great if someone can give a geometric interpretation of such obstruction class.

Thanks in advance for your attention. Let me know if something is not clear in my question!